# Admin tab in exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

How to view admin tab in exact target 2.0. 
I am new to ET so having difficulty in exploring it. 
Screen shots or any kind of help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't see the Admin tab, your user doesn't have permission to view it.

Should look like this:

[image: SFMC Admin]